# How did the USS Kelvin not destroy or at the very least cripple the Narada?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

I may have missed some stuff from the movies, but even accounting for the ship's size, wouldn't crashing the *Kelvin* heavily damage it? again I may have missed stuff, but shouldn't crashing it destroy antimatter containment, making a warp core breach? Also, would the shields be effective, and if so, would the breach would knock it off its course?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see from the deleted scene below, the Narada *was indeed crippled by the destruction of the Kelvin*. The crew are incapable of defending the ship from a fleet of Klingon ships that turn up. They board the Narada and take the crew into custody.

The scene also exists in the [original screenplay.](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek.html)

> The shuttle SAILS AWAY with the others... HOLD ON THIS... for a long beat. Then PAN OVER to see NERO'S SHIP TUMBLING SILENTLY THROUGH SPACE -- DEBRIS still raining from the explosion --
>
> 41    INT. NARADA - BRIDGE - CONTINUOUS
>
> MAYHEM: ALARMS and CREW work to stabilize the ship (OVERLAPPING ROMULAN DIALOG TO BE WRITTEN) -- we arrive at Nero, who, with small specks of HUMAN BLOOD on his face, just STARES at the fucking HOLOGRAM OF SPOCK -- he's OBSESSED.

Comment: I did not know that this deleted scene exists! however I am unable to watch due to the current device being my school computer.

Comment: @MahmoudSalaheddine - A bunch of Klingons turn up. Nero's crew look like they're going to wet themselves. "*This is the Klingon Empire. Surrender or die*", blah blah blah end of scene